# In IntelliJ IDEA, how to surround with try-with-resources?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA, I can press the "*Surround with*" shortcut `CTRL-ALT-T` to surround a block of code with a try / catch block, among other things.

I would like to surround the resource part into a try-with-resources block:

```
Writer out = Files.newBufferedWriter(destination, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
temp.process(model, out);
```

To this:

```
try (Writer out = Files.newBufferedWriter(destination, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    temp.process(model, out);
}
```

However, this option is not available when pressing `CTRL-ALT-T`.

How can I surround a block of code with a try-with-resources block?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Press `ALT-ENTER` on any expression representing an `AutoCloseable`.

"*Surround with try-with-resources block*" is an **Intention action**. It is not an option available in the "*Surround with*" menu.

[image: try with resources screenshot]

Comment: If it's a chained method call, I find I have to extract the `AutoCloseable` into its own variable first.  Specifically, I'm dealing with `java.util.stream.Stream` values, though I'm guessing this is generally true.

Comment: Please, what do you mean by "Intention action", I can't have it in my menu ? how to add it ?

Answer (score 2):

Add `.twr` at the end of your statement.

[image]

[image]