# How can I use intellij to refactor a field into a try-with-resources

Tags: java, intellij-idea, try-with-resources

This question is *similar* to [In IntelliJ IDEA, how to surround with try-with-resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39862408/in-intellij-idea-how-to-surround-with-try-with-resources) but the difference is, I have a field and not a local variable.  My code looks like this:

```
    preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
    preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1);
    preparedStatement.setString(2, "foo");
    preparedStatement.setString(3, "bar");
    preparedStatement.setString(4, "baz");
    preparedStatement.setDouble(5, 0);
    preparedStatement.setDouble(6, 0);
    preparedStatement.setString(7, foovar);
    preparedStatement.setString(8, barvar);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
    preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1);
    preparedStatement.setString(2, "foo2");
    preparedStatement.setString(3, "bar2");
    preparedStatement.setString(4, "baz2");
    preparedStatement.setDouble(5, 0);
    preparedStatement.setDouble(6, 0);
    preparedStatement.setString(7, foovar2);
    preparedStatement.setString(8, barvar2);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

I would like to wrap each one of these so it looks like this::

```
    try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(sqlQuery)) {
        preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, "foo");
        preparedStatement.setString(3, "bar");
        preparedStatement.setString(4, "baz");
        preparedStatement.setDouble(5, 0);
        preparedStatement.setDouble(6, 0);
        preparedStatement.setString(7, foovar);
        preparedStatement.setString(8, barvar);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}

    try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(sqlQuery)) {
        preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, "foo2");
        preparedStatement.setString(3, "bar2");
        preparedStatement.setString(4, "baz2");
        preparedStatement.setDouble(5, 0);
        preparedStatement.setDouble(6, 0);
        preparedStatement.setString(7, foovar2);
        preparedStatement.setString(8, barvar2);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}
```

And I'd really like to do this by only using IDE refactoring shortcuts.  Is this possible?  The most challenging part, in my mind, is turning this field into a local variable.  Once I've done that, I think I could figure out the rest.

Comment: if you are familiar with vim you could use the idea vim plugin to do the job via macro

Comment: @snap what does intellij add to that?  Would there be a difference between this and just using a macro?

Comment: no it can jusy be used directly inside idea. in fact it's less powerfull then doing it directly in vim.

Comment: @snap less powerful in what way?

Comment: It "just" a emulated subset of vim and don't support all functionality of vim. And you don't be able to add plugins to it (but it have some like surrounding already integrated). don't get me wrong idea vim plugin is really cool but for real tricky stuff i have to switch to the real vim. but for the purpose here it should work pretty well. here you can read about all supported features: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/164-ideavim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible, since this refactoring can have adverse effects for any other user of the connection.

Given that your connection is at a higher scope than method, it stands to reason that there *may* be other downstream users of this connection instance.  With that in mind, if there is the possibility of other downstream users, closing the connection from underneath their feet would result in unexpected or aberrant behavior.

IntelliJ is declaring here that its code analyzer cannot reliably guarantee that this variable isn't being used by any other downstream consumer.  You may want to request this as a feature.

<sup>I personally like it *not* allowing this to happen, since it saves the developer from doing something ***incredibly*** stupid without them realizing it.</sup>

Comment: Cool, that makes sense.  I wouldn't want to request it for that reason.  Can a structural search and replace help me here, maybe?  Yeah, that bug is why I'm asking for the question ;)

Comment: I think a rearchitecture of the connections may be useful.  Instead of using the instance's connection directly, refactor it so you can get a `Supplier<Connection>` back which provides a relatively fresh connection.

Comment: I think I misunderstood.  Where's the massive bug?  I thought it was from not closing the statement.  Seems like you're saying the bug is in using the connection directly.  I'm using DBCP and its examples do this.

Comment: Actually, disregard.  That was me interpolating `PreparedStatement` as `Connection`.